# How would a dual-government country with a cordon and central zone make sense?

Tags: society

I want a utopian seeming country that consists of 'cordon' and 'central' zones. The central zone is supposed to be an open-border, somewhat anarchistic area with an immigrant influx, automated industry and agriculture for basic commodities, and a focus on assigning newcomers into educational, environmental and cultural 'improvement' efforts. And the cordon zone is supposed to envelop this area with a high degree of militarization, high tech industry and strict border controls aside from the controlled passes into the center and the limited, highly controlled immigration from the center.

My idea is a character hailing from a war-torn land with his family moving to the center with promises of work and a life with dignity, just to find himself in the middle of a series of events revealing the reality beyond the utopian facade where the cordoners have much higher living standards and get to control the said standards for the centrals.

What are some things I would need to keep in mind to make this a stable enough, believable society?

Comment: Oh, I've heard of *The Dispossessed*. No, you did not take that mind boggling phrase from it. And anyway, my suggestion is really for real; really, do it. Write down / list / make a story board of a day in the life of one of the corrupt exploiters. Show what makes them corrupt. Show whom they exploit, and in what way they use them to wage cultural war. Show how they enslave them. Then explore the implications: say a corrupt exploiter enslaves one of the exploited. What does this imply? How does the enslaved exploitee vanish from the society? Doesn't anybody investigate? Relatives?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but let's try. (1) Nobody is *corrupt* in *The Dispossessed*. On the contrary, everybody believes that what they do is good. (2) It's not clear that the miners on the moon feel exploited. (This is actually one of the great artistic ambiguities of the book -- who is exploiting whom, and it there exploitation going on or not?) (3) There is no aristocratic caste, or at least I don't remember anything of the kind. (4) It is not clear which of the two societies is actually more or less oppressive. (And that is one of the important points.)

Comment: Sure Urras is capitalist, not aristocratic in that sense. Still exploiting Anarres though, in exchange of not overthrowing their system they get their desert moon as a de facto colony. But if Urras was a more regimented, militarized society with a fraction of citizens by birthright compared to Anarres, gatekeeping military and high tech, it would be aristocratic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You Might Look at China for a Lot of Your Model

> The central zone is supposed to be an open-border, somewhat anarchistic area with an immigrant influx, automated industry and agriculture for basic commodities, and a focus on assigning newcomers into educational, environmental and cultural 'improvement' efforts.

Rural China is roughly 47% of the national population of 1.4 billion people. It has porous boarders, manual agriculture, and multiple systems devoted to cultural improvement of the people.

Citizens living outside the cities do not enjoy social services. They do not receive retirement pensions, or health care. Some (8%) do not even having running water or public sanitation. Nevertheless, [every resident is registered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hukou) with the government.

> And the cordon zone is supposed to envelop this area with a high degree of militarization, high tech industry and strict border controls aside from the controlled passes into the center and the limited, highly controlled immigration from the center.

Urban China includes megaplexes like Shanghai (23 million people), Beijin (18 million people), Wuhan (11 million people), Taiwan and Hong Kong. A significant amount of high-tech is going on here. And it is the manufacturing centers of the nation.

Immigration into the cities is tightly controlled. Citizens from rural China are not automatically permitted to immigrate. People from the [rural areas are smuggled into the city](https://www.migrationpolicy.org/article/chinas-young-rural-urban-migrants-search-fortune-happiness-and-independence/) where they are forced into hiding like other illegal immigrants.

Comment: Interesting, this is definitely along the lines of what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorS, the key thing to both this answer and mine is that the border zone *prevents* unchecked immigration into the center. That's what the zone is there for.

Comment: @o.m. why is it such a critical point though? If the border has stake in the center population being large and checks for incoming immigration from it, what's the problem?

Comment: @VictorS, I see the relationship between center and border as symbiotic, the center pays for the border guards and exploits the those stuck at the border, and what it gets from that is protection from having to stop refugees by themselves. If entry to the center becomes easy, the center **is** the "border region" of the state.

Comment: Yes and no in my scenario. If any temporary immigration, diplomacy, media activity etc. happens at the 'cordon' with only permanent migration into the center as allowed through it, then it is the border region.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense as you describe it. But consider this alternative:

- The **inner zone** looks like a modern, liberal democracy. Except that they are delusional about the effects of their policies. *To an outside observer, it might almost look like an utopian anarchy, because the rule enforcement mechanisms are politely hidden away.*

  - Generally there is law and order. So much of it that the police can afford to go around [unarmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_use_of_firearms_in_the_United_Kingdom), except for highly trained specialists.
  - High levels of education and a high investment in infrastructure increase the [productivity](https://www.weforum.org/reports/how-to-end-a-decade-of-lost-productivity-growth) per man-hour. This allows a decent wage with both a modest average working week (call it 30 to 40 hours) and a high percentage of taxes and deductions (call it 50% or more). *Even if the state takes half the wage, there is plenty left to live on.*
  - This allows a welfare system which allows unemployed citizens/residents adequate food, clothing, shelter, and health case.
  - In reality, much of this apparent affluence comes from exploiting people in the outer zone and completely outside. Dirty, dangerous, and low-paid jobs are outsourced so that they are no longer visible in the inner zone.
  - To *make* the welfare payment adequate, there must be cheap food, cheap clothing. They come from low-paid sweat shops in the outer zone.
  - Both the welfare recipients and the average workers have **no idea** just how productive their society really is, and how much wealth ends up in the pockets of the capitalist investors. They are happily working (or *not* working and meekly saying 'thank you') for crumbs from the table while others pocket the entire pie.
- The **outer zone** is formally part of the same liberal democracy, but "special rules apply" to secure the borders.

  - The border guard force (from the people walking the fences to those setting policy) may be *institutionally corrupt* in the sense of a **military-industrial** or **prison-industrial complex**. Most don't take *bribes* individually, but they advocate a policy which secures and expands their *jobs*. And if there are another 100,000 border guards added to the roster, why, the veterans currently on the force will get their well-deserved promotion and wage rise.
  - There could also be some *personal corruption* -- cash, valuable goods, or sex for being allowed to pass through (or for not getting beaten too badly). Single guards who take petty cash to accept an obviously forged passport, administrators who make sure that a certain truck is never searched to start with, ...
  - There are refugee camps with people who are not allowed into the inner zone, yet who cannot be sent away easily. (Outer zone guards would do it in a heartbeat, but inner zone citizens couldn't stomach it. They cherish their illusions.)
  - To give those refugees something to do, there are *special economic zones* within the outer zone where the minimum wage rules from the inner zone do not apply. Worker safety and environmental rules apply in theory, but they are not effectively enforced.
  - Capitalists from the inner zone profit from these sweatshops, just like those who administer and guard them.
- Obviously there are no open passages through the outer zone. It was created to shield the inner zone from the reality beyond their borders.

**Any similarities to the current global system are wildly exaggerated, of course.**

Your outside character could come into the outer zone, with preconceptions based on the public image of the inner zone, and get severely disappointed. From his or her viewpoint, the guards would be aristocrats, making capricious decisions. To someone with the "right" passport, they're not aristocrats, they're somewhere between a flunky and a valued professional.